# Sonata admin bundle order

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

How to change default entity order in SonataAdminBundle for list action?

---

answer :)
add this to your admin class

> ```
> protected $datagridValues = array(
>     '_page' => 1,
>     '_sort_order' => 'DESC', // sort direction 
>     '_sort_by' => 'id' // field name 
> );
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add another sort order or set a default one via the constructor like this:

```
public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName)
{
    parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);

    if (!$this->hasRequest()) {
        $this->datagridValues = array(
            '_page'       => 1,
            '_sort_order' => 'ASC',      // sort direction
            '_sort_by'    => 'artist_id' // field name
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for Neon\CoreBundle\Controller\OrderAdminController::__construct()..`

Comment: put please here list of namespaces you used

Answer (score 9):

It is better not to override constructor.
But you can override the `Admin::configure()` method and set some element of the `datagridValues` array.

See in example:

```php
public function configure()
{
    parent::configure();

    $this->datagridValues['_sort_by']    = 'name';
    $this->datagridValues['_sort_order'] = 'DESC';
}
```

Comment: To be safe, I would also add `parent::configure()`.

Comment: This method is empty. it exists for just such situations. If I understand correctly. But you're right, will be safer to call the parent method. I adjusted the example.