# Sonata admin - "order by" field in related table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, admin

I have a Product admin class. The Product entity has a many-to-one relationship with a Category entity, i.e. a product is associated with a category.

In the admin "list" page for products, I need to sort by the category name (alphabetically) that each product is associated with.

Setting the default field to sort by is easy if the field is on the entity itself (see [Sonata admin bundle order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120787/sonata-admin-bundle-order) for how to do this). But I cannot figure out how to sort by a field in a related table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153381/sort-list-view-in-sonata-admin-by-related-entity-fields). It has an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems a workaround, but it works. You have to add a join overriding createQuery() method, than assign a default sortBy overriding $datagridValues:

```
<?php
use Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery;

class ExpenseAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $datagridValues = array(
        '_page'       => 1,
        '_sort_order' => 'ASC', // sort direction
        '_sort_by' => 'c.name' // field name
    );

    /**
     * @return \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQueryInterface
     */
    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $query = parent::createQuery($context);

        return new ProxyQuery($query
            ->join(sprintf('%s.category', $query->getRootAlias()), 'c'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I still need to try it but it seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Asume `name` is the property of entity `Category` by wich you want to sort. You may do this in you `ProductAdmin.php`

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{

     $listMapper->add('category.name', null, array(
            'sortable' => true,
     ));
     ...
}
```

This way you leverage the ordering links in the header of the list, generated by Sonata.

**Edit**

If you would also like to have a link on the category name in products list to quickly edit the `Category` entity, assuming you have created a `CategoryAdmin` class, you should write your code like this:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{

     $listMapper->add('category', null, array(
            'sortable' => 'category.name',
     ));
     ...
}
```

And in your `Category` class you should implement the `__toString()` method like this:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
```

Comment: This worked with `KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors` translatable `->add('name', null, array('associated_property' => 'EntityTranslation','sortable' => 'translations.name'))`