# Sonata Admin List View, make more headers sort buttons?

Tags: php, sorting, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have an Admin class which has this definition of listFields:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('type')
            ->add('created_at', 'datetime')
            ->add('updated_at', 'datetime')
            ->add('created_by')
            ->add('updated_by')
            ->add('is_active')
            ->add('is_deleted')
            ->add('_action', 'actions',
                    array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'view' => array(),
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array()
                )
            ))
    ;

}
```

Only the "type" column is sortable - IE, when you hover over the table header for "Type" you see an asc/desc arrow and can click to re-order the rows based on this column.

How do I get that to show up on more columns?

I tried adding sortable=true but then it's trying to join to another Entity.

Comment: Could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120787/sonata-admin-bundle-order

Comment: I've read that one, it's just about setting the default sort field. I want to have sorting on more columns. (Not at the same time, I just want the option to sort other columns instead of the first one)

Comment: @Jessica Were you able to solve the issue..?? If yes please share it here. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I did not yet. I just came back to it after working on other stuff and googled the error again and found my own thread :-P I cannot do the suggestion to use a specific field in the entity because I am relying on the entity __toString function to print it. I will have to decide to either:
A. Use a specific field
B. Not sort the field
C. Extend Sonata and allow it to sort an entity by the __toString value (which would mean the sorting is in PHP and not MySQL and clearly much slower)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
# we can sort the related entity properties like. This following condition site is an entity

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name')
        ->add('site',null,array(
            'sortable'=>true,
            'sort_field_mapping'=> array('fieldName'=>'name'),
            'sort_parent_association_mappings' => array(array('fieldName'=>'site')
            )))
    ;
}
```

this is the way to sort the related entities in list configuration.
Just check this [Sort list by an entity field](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1035)

Answer (score 4):

Sonata will be able to sort a field if it knows what type it is ; if you list a related entity, it will be impossible to sort.

Here is the *configureListFields()* from an entity **"Event"** which has a title and is linked to another entity **"City"**.

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('title')
            ->add('city')
}
```

A link will be created to the city but it will not be sortable, instead adding a specific field from "City" will work :

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('title')
        ->add('city.name')
}
```

Now it's sortable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `sortable` option on the field.

Here is the code i use:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name')
        ->add('application', null, array('sortable' => true))
        ->add('isActive', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'view' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: "I tried adding sortable=true but then it's trying to join to another Entity."

Comment: This is the exact error I get using that code 
    Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery::entityJoin() must be of the type array, null given, called in /vagrant/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Datagrid/ProxyQuery.php on line 140 and defined in /vagrant/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Datagrid/ProxyQuery.php line 245

Comment: In my case, the entity linked to the admin didn't contain the field i was listing. The field I'm list is from a child entity. Sonata tries to find metadata about what to do with the field but cant find any because it's from a child class so it tries to find a relation.